# Is there a way to create a custom calendar using a holiday and weekend list in quantlib

Tags: quantlib

We have a data set up that provides us a list of holidays and weekends which is different from the country or currency calendars.Is there any method exposed in Quantlib calendars which expects a list of holday dates and weekends to form a calendar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to permanently add holidays to QuantLib calendars?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30905/how-to-permanently-add-holidays-to-quantlib-calendars) You can change .cpp files in ql/time/calendars/ and rebuild ql, or you can use BespokeCalendar, read your data file and call addHoliday() for each date at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
myCalendar = ql.WeekendsOnly()
dates = ['19-06-2019', '07-05-2020']
for date in dates:
    myCalendar.addHoliday( ql.Date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') )
```

Or if for some reason the weekends are different, start from `ql.NullCalendar()`

Comment: This will modify all instances of `WeekendsOnly` and make it something different. Also, it can only be done for one calendar.  I suggest using `BespokeCalendar` instead.